# Call Visualforce Component function from another Visualforce Component

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, jquery

I need help: How to call Visualforce Component function  from  another Visualforce Component. Below are Code details. i.e call `'display.component'` click function from `'view.component'`

1st Component: view.component

```
<apex:component>
    <script id="View" type="text/template">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary myBtn">Click</button>
    </script>
</apex:component>
```

2nd Component: display.component

```
<apex:component>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.myBtn').click(function () {
            alert("Hello")
        });
    });
</script>
</apex:component>
```

Answer (score 1):

your selector for the click method is wrong.It should look like below

```
$('.myBtn').click(function () {
      alert("Hello")
       });
});
```

Comment: Hi vppravi93 .I just edited  element to class.but is it works because I have to call other component function?